# UITableView Not Smooth Scrolling during dynamic cell contents change based on the settings

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a Table View that rows data display basis on the user settings. 
Like I have check box for Task, Start Date, Priority , Process, State , Description Etc.

I user check Task and Description then I create `UITableViewCell` then Add Label for Task And Description if user check All the Settings then Cell should Display all the Label created.

What Problem I am facing is that `UITableView` Not Scrolling smoothly its not reusing the cell when user scrolls it second Time after Loading the settings.

Below is the code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellMainNibID = @"cellMain";
    NSUInteger count=[arrSettings count];
    TaskItem* item=[self.arrTaskList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    CGFloat y=2;
    UITableViewCell* cell=(UITableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellMainNibID];
    if (_cellMain == nil)
    {

        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellMainNibID];


        for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
        {
            UILabel *lbll=(UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:indexPath.row+ i+200];
            NSLog(@" cell label = %@",lbll); //**Return null always**
            UILabel* lbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, y, 310, 14)];
            lbl.tag=indexPath.row+ i+200;
            lbl.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
            lbl.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
            lbl.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];

            [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl];
            lbl=nil;


            NSString* str=[arrSettings objectAtIndex:i];
            CGRect rect;
            if ([str isEqualToString:@"description"])
                rect=CGRectMake(8, y+14, 290, 50);

            else
                rect=CGRectMake(110, y, 290, 14);

            UILabel *lblll=(UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:indexPath.row+ i+400];
            NSLog(@" cell label = %@",lblll); //**Return null always**

            UILabel* lbl2=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:rect];
            lbl2.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
            lbl2.tag=indexPath.row+i+400;
            lbl2.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
            lbl2.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];

            lbl2.numberOfLines=5;
            lbl2.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByCharWrapping;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl2];
            y+=lbl2.frame.size.height+1;
            lbl2=nil;

        }
    }

    for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        UILabel* lbl=(UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:indexPath.row+i+200];
        lbl.text=[[[arrSettings objectAtIndex:i]uppercaseString]stringByAppendingString:@":"];

        UILabel* lbl2=(UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:indexPath.row+i+400];
        lbl2.text=[item valueForKey:[arrSettings objectAtIndex:i]];
    }






    cell.contentView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    _cellMain.contentView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    _cellMain.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    UIButton *btnCheck=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    btnCheck.tag=indexPath.row+300;
    if ([arrSelectedRow containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithLong:btnCheck.tag-300]])
    {
        [btnCheck setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cb_glossy_on@2x.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else
    {
        [btnCheck setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cb_glossy_off@2x.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    btnCheck.frame=CGRectMake(295, cell.center.y-22, 33, 33);
    [btnCheck addTarget:self action:@selector(checkClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    cell.accessoryView=btnCheck;
    btnCheck=nil;

    return cell;
}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSUInteger count=[arrSettings count];
    CGFloat totalHeight=(16*count)+(count*2);
    if (isDesc)
        totalHeight+=60;
    return totalHeight;

}
```

Could anyone please suggest me how to display the dynamic data in `UITableView` based on User Settings for `UITableViewCell` Labels ?

Comment: this is just way way too much going on for `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: Then do you have any idea how to create label and display basis on user settings in UITableView ?

Comment: you are also not checking on the cell: `if (_cellMain == nil)` but not `cell`

Comment: @meda you awesome , now its reusing the cell but if user to go settings then check some more labels then it loading the previous labels only so I will have to check if user comes from settings then it must not reuse the cell that time. 

BTW thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
if (_cellMain == nil)
```

to

```
if (cell == nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add following code in your cellForRowAtIndex method of UITableView

```
cell.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
cell.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem with not smooth tableView scrolling. In my case the reason was in what I forgot to implement tableView method `tableView: registerNib: forCellReuseIdentifier:` (in that project I used .xib's to create cells).

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"YourTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:YourCellReuseIdentifier];
```